# Check for a UIViewController transition in UIAutomation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

How can I check for the modal transition of a `UIViewController` in `UIAutomation`?

Comment: Found the problem... Used delay. UIATarget.localTarget().delay(2);